# Having trouble getting a custom hook to work with Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

As you can tell from the code, I'm trying to make a custom hook that would sort the rendered cards.

When the cards first render, they show up in the default order from the API, but they get sorted only after forcing a re-render, usually by pressing Ctrl+S to save so Vite registers a change.

I'm new to custom hooks so I don't really know what I'm doing wrong, probably a problem with the dispatches inside the useEffect? How can I get the cards to sort properly?

This is the custom hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
// Redux
import { getAllBosses, SortBosses } from '../redux/slices/Bosses';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export default function useFetch(value) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { list: bosses } = useSelector(state => state.bosses);
    const [type, setType] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        value === 'default'
            ? dispatch(getAllBosses())
            : dispatch(SortBosses(value));
        setType(bosses);
    }, [value]);

    return type;
}
```

And this is the component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
// Redux
// import { getAllBosses } from '../../redux/slices/Bosses';
// import {  useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

// components
import { BossCard, Loading, Pagination, Error } from '@components';

import { useFetch } from '../../hooks';

import { Cards } from '@components/styles/Cards.style';

function BossesList() {
    // const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const bosses = useFetch('ztoa');
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const bossPerPage = 8;
    const indexOfLastBoss = currentPage * bossPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstBoss = indexOfLastBoss - bossPerPage;
    const currentBosses = bosses.slice(indexOfFirstBoss, indexOfLastBoss);

    const pages = pageNumber => {
        setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
    };

    

    // useEffect(() => {
    //  dispatch(getAllBosses());
    // }, [dispatch]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setCurrentPage(1);
    }, [bosses]);

    return (
        <>
            <Cards>
                {currentBosses.length !== 0 ? (
                    currentBosses.map((boss, index) =>
                        boss.error ? (
                            <Error key={index} error={'No boss with that name.'} />
                        ) : (
                            <BossCard
                                key={boss.id}
                                id={boss.id}
                                name={boss.name}
                                image={boss.image}
                            />
                        )
                    )
                ) : (
                    <div>
                        <Loading />
                    </div>
                )}
            </Cards>
            <Pagination
                bossPerPage={bossPerPage}
                bosses={bosses.length}
                currentBosses={currentBosses}
                pages={pages}
                currentPage={currentPage}
            />
        </>
    );
}

export default BossesList;
```

Comment: You have pasted the same code twice

Comment: You want to get the `bosses` info and you are not getting it? or what's the trouble?

Comment: @FerToasted No, the bosses info arrives just fine, the problem is it doesn't sort unless Vite registers a change in the code, which is really strange.